# Make a process calculate the time spent

Tags: c, process, operating-system

I'm creating a `tree of process` and I need to make a process execute the `Time` command. When working in terminal you can:

```
Time ./myExec
```

Besides the `process-tree` I also need to show the time used to execute my application, so I thought it would be a good idea to make one of my process execute this instead of writing it myself in terminal.

How may I do that ??

A piece of my code that creates my tree:

```
pid_t idProcesso; // P1
    idProcesso = fork();

    switch(idProcesso){
        case -1: exit(-1); //ERROR
        case 0: //P2
            printf("sou P2: %d  |  meu pai P1: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
            idProcesso = fork();
            switch(idProcesso){
                case -1: exit(-1); //Error
                case 0: //P4
                    printf("Sou P4: %d  |  meu pai P2: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                    break;

                default: //Continuação de P2
                wait(&status);
                printf("Sou P2: %d  |  já esperei meu filho P4: %d\n", getpid(), idProcesso);
                idProcesso = fork(); //P5
                switch(idProcesso){
                    case -1: exit(-1); //ERROR
                    case 0: //P5
                        printf("Sou P5: %d  |  meu pai P2: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                        break;
                    default: //Continuacao de P5
                        wait(&status); //P2 espera seu filho P5
                        printf("Sou P2: %d  |  já esperei meu filho P5: %d\n", getpid(), idProcesso);

                }
            }
```

If not possible to do it (becasue we use it when we execute the file) a better way to measure the time than mine (Alaways returns 0):

```
clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;
    begin = clock();  //Start counting time
    pid_t idProcesso; // P1
        idProcesso = fork();

        switch(idProcesso){
            case -1: exit(-1); //ERROR
            case 0: //P2
                printf("sou P2: %d  |  meu pai P1: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                idProcesso = fork();
                switch(idProcesso){
                    case -1: exit(-1); //Error
                    case 0: //P4
                        printf("Sou P4: %d  |  meu pai P2: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                        break;

                    default: //Continuação de P2
                    wait(&status);
                    printf("Sou P2: %d  |  já esperei meu filho P4: %d\n", getpid(), idProcesso);
                    idProcesso = fork(); //P5
                    switch(idProcesso){
                        case -1: exit(-1); //ERROR
                        case 0: //P5
                            printf("Sou P5: %d  |  meu pai P2: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                            break;
                        default: //Continuacao de P5
                            wait(&status); //P2 espera seu filho P5
                            printf("Sou P2: %d  |  já esperei meu filho P5: %d\n", getpid(), idProcesso);

                    }
                }  
end = clock();
                    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                    printf("Tempo Gasto: %.2f \n", time_spent);
```

Obs: I'm using Linux.

Comment: What operating system are you using for this?

Comment: @EOF Sorry  I forgot to tell. Linux > Ubuntu distr.

Comment: Great! In that case, you've surely read `man 3 clock [...] Linux does not include the  times  of waited-for  children  in the value returned by clock().` How is the behavior you've encountered surprising to you?

Comment: @EOF Ya, know I see.. :\ Any tips ?

Comment: Surely, since you've now read `man 3 clock` you also read the *very next sentence therein* `The times(2) function, which explicitly returns (separate) information about the caller  and its children, may be preferable.`